# Cannot convert form List<File> to List<Path>

Tags: java

Obviously, it's not possible to convert from List<File> to List<Path>. I was trying to do that because JFileChooser returns an array of File objects. Now, I'm just curious if there's a more elegant (functional) approach in Java than using a loop.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File[] array = new File[] { new File("a.txt"), new File("b.txt"),
      new File("c.txt"), new File("d.txt") };

    // Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<File> to List<Path>
    // List<Path> list = Arrays.asList(array);

    // This will work but is not particularly pretty
    List<Path> list = new ArrayList<Path>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      list.add(array[i].toPath());
    }

    System.out.println(list);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can already use a better loop

```
for(File f: array) {
  list.add(f.toPath();
}
```

Then, if you are using Java 8, you can use the new stream using something like:

```
final List<Path> list = Arrays.stream(array).map(File::toPath)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Erm no, there is no `.stream()` method on arrays; you have to `Arrays.stream(array)`. And you have to `.collect(Collectors.toList())` at the end too (fixed that for you)

Comment: Of note is that the "good old" loop syntax is shorter here :p

Comment: Thanks! I should really fire an editor instead of doing that on top of my head. Any pointer/reference about the "old loop" being faster?

Comment: No, I meant "shorter to write" actually (fixed the text)

Comment: Sorry, still stuck with the good old C-style for-loop sometimes. :) The latter approach is kind of what I was anticipating, thanks for that. I should stick with Java 7 for compatibility reasons, but I definitely like this kind of approach.